# How to open files in /tmp with snap applications

Tags: snap, tmp

I thought running something like `snap connect app_name:/tmp` would work but it didn't. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: What errors (if any) did you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow snap applications to access /tmp folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263843/how-to-allow-snap-applications-to-access-tmp-folder)