# Some applications can't read or write to mounted NTFS partition: Permission denied

Tags: partitioning, permissions, kubuntu, ntfs

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 in dualboot with Windows 8.1 and i have a NTFS partition /dev/sda5 mounted at /data. All default Kubuntu applications, like Dolphin file manager, KTorrent etc can read and write to that partition without any problem. But when i installed some applications i noticed that they don't have permissions to read or write to /data.

My fstab line: `UUID=3A8A31E98A31A1F5 /data ntfs defaults,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

[youtube-dl can't open file for writing inside /data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJkR9.png)
[Discord file opener doesn't see the data folder, while it's visible in dolphin file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLix0.png)

List of things that i have tried:

- I heard that Windows sets read-only flag to NTFS partitions before shutting down, so i booted into Windows, disabled Fast Boot and Hibernation and rebooted instead of shutting down. Didn't work.
- Modified permissions using `sudo chmod -r ugo-rw /data`, didn't work
- Unmounted /dev/sda5 and remounted it with read and write permissions
  `sudo umount /dev/sda5`
  `sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=022 /dev/sda5 /data`
  Didn't work
- Modified fstab file to include my uid and gid
  `UUID=3A8A31E98A31A1F5 /data ntfs defaults,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`
  and remounted the partition. Didn't work.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does it work without `windows_names` in `/etc/fstab`? I am able to download with youtube-dl on a NTFS mounted with `defaults,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000`. I found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) that `windows_names` will **prevent** creation of files with chars that windows doesn't like.

Comment: Also, I'm not too sure your `umask=7000`. What does it do?

Comment: i changed umask to 007 and removed windows_names, remounted and youtube-dl still throws unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: Could you please try the '--output' option of youtube-dl? Use a name that is acceptable for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used snaps to install youtube-dl, either:

remove youtube-dl and install it through some other method (other than snaps)

or

mount your device in your home directory something like this [How to allow snap applications to access /tmp folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263843/how-to-allow-snap-applications-to-access-tmp-folder/1264341#1264341)