# How can I grant permission to snap application (evince) (ubuntu 18.4) to open files outside home?

Tags: 18.04, snap, evince, apparmor

I have installed evince through snap in ubuntu 18.04 and only opens files inside home folder.

```
** (evince:6214): WARNING **: 00:03:47.818: set_filenames: Error when getting information for file “/SCRATCH/pnas.201707945.pdf”: No such file or directory
```

I have found a similar problems in other snap installed packages and seems that the problem is related with apparmor.

I don't want to switch off apparmor, I only want to know how to allow for each snap a set of folders where they can have access. Probably different ones by snap app.

Comment: It's not a problem. That's a security feature of snaps called sandboxing. If you want to do without that feature then you'd use the apt version of the software vs the snap version. If you don't have that option and your config HAS to refer to some directory outside of the home directory, then you can fool it with my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263843 (the other answer there is kind of, excuse the critique, absurd. That person is just creating a similarly named folder in the home directory and using it; which you already know you can do..and then deleting it for some reason)

Comment: Thanks @WU-TANG, sorry for the wrong wording, It is not a problem with the software, was a problem for me, as a user. Usually I have these external folders as a symlink, but I can mount them in home as well.